# Tarry substance on vinyl floor

Tags: cleaning, bathroom, house-cleaning

I'm trying to clean up the house for my elderly mother who's in hospital. The bathroom floor has a slick of black tar-like substance running from the sink out the door to the landing.

Firstly it's definitely not faeces or similar. I believe it probably started as an unknown sticky spillage and was gummied up with a black tarry substance from the bottom of her shoes. I've seen evidence of this elsewhere.

It's difficult to budge as it has dried well in and I don't want to damage the vinyl flooring. Any suggestions as to how to remove it and also what cleaners I should avoid using on vinyl?

Comment: Test a solvent on a small area at the edge.